# No GC when application is in idle state

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, performance-testing

I'm having spring-boot based microservice. It's high throughput read service. I've noticed that if I leave the server running for longer time (few hours or a day) without putting any load, G1 Eden space keeps growing and no GC happens during this period. As a result, as soon as I start sending traffic to the server, GC will kick in and GC time would be longer than in general (almost double from 240 ms to 480 ms). This would keep the threads in the busy state for a short duration and leads to request timeout on the client side.

```
Java version: 1.8.0_131
Current load: 450 TPS
GC: G1GC
Heap Parameter used:
-Xms4g
-Xmx4g
-XX:NewRatio=2
-XX:SurvivorRatio=8
-XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90
-XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:MetaspaceSize=640m
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=640m
-Xss512k
-XX:+UseG1GC
```

**Questions:**
1) Why there is no GC activity while the server is at an idle state? 
2) Why do we spike in GC time during the initial stage of the GC which pauses all the threads for a little longer period? 
3) Why do we see a spike in G1 survivor space?

[image]

Comment: What is your actual question here?   Why did you choose those particular GC settings?  Have you tried just `-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=<nnn>` and letting the GC tune to meet a "pause time" goal?  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/ergonomics.html#sthref12

Comment: While it doesn't answer your question, have you considered using `System.gc()` to manually invoke the garbage collector during idle periods?

Comment: @apemanzilla I haven't tried System.gc() before sending traffic. Probably if I do that, we may not see the issue but as you also agree that it's not a practical solution.